# Unable to access Native .so files in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, libraries

I am trying to add **armeabi .so** files in my Android Studio project. Which will be accessed by **.jar** files of an SDK. Basically I am using Brothers Printers SDK and integrating them in my app. *THe problem is, the .jar files are picked up in the Android Studio Project but when I try to access a method of the SDK, it gives me this error:*

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load createdata from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wingoku.printerapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.wingoku.printerapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
at com.brother.ptouch.sdk.JNIWrapper.<clinit>(JNIWrapper.java:16)
at com.brother.ptouch.sdk.Printer.setPrinterInfo(Printer.java:887)
at com.wingoku.printerapp.print.printprocess.BasePrint.setPrinterInfo(BasePrint.java:73)
at com.wingoku.printerapp.print.printprocess.BasePrint$PrinterThread.run(BasePrint.java:433)
```

I have tried putting the armeabi folder inside the `src/main/jniLibs` but the **.so** files are not getting picked up and I keep getting the mentioned exception.

What can I do resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The method which helped me is:

make a directory on your desktop name it 'lib'
take your jnilibs folders with *.so files and paste it in lib.

now `zip your lib` folder
and then change its extention from `.zip` to `.jar`
that is `lib.zip` to `lib.jar`

now copy this into your libs folder of your project and update you gradle by adding this line in dependencies:

`compile fileTree(include: 'lib.jar',dir:'libs')`

this is the safest method to load any jnilibs. i applied it with opencv libs

if also problem persists add reference of NDK-root in your app.

hope this helps.